# Moving location towards a target location

Tags: java, geolocation

I have two locations (latitude, longitude), one being the current location and the other being a target. What I would like to do is to have a loop that moves the current location towards the target location in stages. I am not entirely sure on the maths of getting the current location to the target location.

Comment: Which type of path you looking for ? Straight line or curve or any zigzag path ?

Comment: Try [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm). It is very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Rough Demo Code to achieve all points in stages between two points.I Hope it would be of your help:

```
import java.awt.Point;
public class  Path
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Point start         = new Point(0,0);
        Point destination   = new Point(100,150);
        int   iStages = 9;//Suppose I want to reach to destination in 9 jumps
        int   jumpX = (destination.x - start.x) / iStages;
        int   jumpY = (destination.y - start.y) / iStages;
        Point currPos = start;
        for (int i = 0; i < iStages ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(currPos);
            currPos = new Point(currPos.x + jumpX , currPos.y + jumpY );
        }
        currPos = new Point(destination.x , destination.y);
        System.out.println(currPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking to make the distance travelled for each step constant instead of the number of steps. So for example if you started at 0,0 it would take twice as many steps to get to 100,100 as to get to 50,50. Would this be a case of calculating the iStages based on the distance between the two points?

Comment: You mean that If the path is `from point(10,10) to point (100,100)` or `from point(32,23) to point(50,60)` in both case  you want each step length to be constant say `d = 10` ?

Comment: I wanted to base the number of steps on the distance between the points. So I took the distance and divided that by an arbitrary number and used that for the number of steps which works perfectly. Thank you for your help.